# PrimeNg remove severity icon

Tags: angular, primeng

How do I remove the **X** icon?

[image]

```
<p-message severity="error" text="*" *ngIf="!form.controls['name'].valid ">
</p-message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a style to suppress it:

```
.ui-message-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: am i just add this code in the component.css file? i had try add in component.css file and this html code <p-message severity="error" text="*" *ngIf="!form.controls['name'].valid ">
</p-message> just remain the same. The 'X' icon still appear. If i add it as a class, whole the message box is remove, including the message i want to show out. Am i do a mistake?

Comment: So, you have to add it to your global styles, because shadow dom styles don't pierce into sub components.  ie, your component style will only apply to elements in your component HTML, and not trickle down into sub components.  Until PrimeNG creates and exposes CSS variables, it's either use global styles or soon to be removed shadow-piercing `:host ::ng-deep .ui-message-icon { ... }`.  Keep in mind that `:host ::ng-deep` is deprecated and will be removed from a future version of angular. Complicated. See for more details: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: i had use ':host ::ng-deep .ui-message-icon { display: none; }' it still appear. html code is still remain same '<p-message severity="error" text="*" *ngIf="!form.controls['name'].valid ">
</p-message>'

Comment: Are you sure your component's css/scss file is loading?  Have you inspected the element with Chrome's/Firefox's inspector?

Comment: It worked. had solved it. Maybe is due to browser cache problem. today when i debug it. the icon had removed already. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
 :host::ng-deep ui-messages-icon {
       display: none;
    }
```